# What species is this black, blue and white bird?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, ornithology

I think this species is native to **[Edmonton, Alberta, Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonton)**, as I see it regularly, especially around the urban locality (Downtown Edmonton).

**Season: Early Spring**

**Date: May 18, 2017**

**Basic Description:** Medium sized bird, and I was not able to observe a characteristic chirp from the bird while I was taking a photograph. Most distinctive feature is the ***[bright royal bluish gradient](http://mozdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/MozMetals_Classic_Royal-Blue_fog_main.jpg)*** on the *tail* and *tips of the wings*.

[image: Bird Picture ONE]

[image: Bird Picture TWO]

Comment: If you were in the UK, you'd now have to say "Good morning Mr Magpie. How is your lady wife today?". It's practically a law.

Comment: I once took some pictures of this bird while in Africa (in Zaire, as it  was called then.) The onlookers laughed at me (quietly and affebly). It was so common in Zaire it would be like someone marveling at a pigeon in NYC. Good memory, thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That bird is commonly called a [magpie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magpie). The only species found in Alberta is [*Pica hudsonia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-billed_magpie). You can see a reference image on the left and their distribution throughout Canada on the right:

[image]
[image]

[[source](http://www.thecanadianencyclopedia.ca/en/article/magpie/)]

Interestingly, [it is one of the only non-mammals studied that is able to recognize itself in a mirror](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.0060202&type=printable). In fact, [these and other corvids are thought to be some of the most intelligent species on Earth](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15591194).

You mentioned that you didn't hear them chirp. These birds are actually quite loud and about fifty of them used to wake me up every morning. [Have a listen](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=60Zg9sGnQf8) (not my video).

Comment: Your attached video makes me realize how lucky I am to not have heard the bird chirp.

Comment: @ImtiazRaqib Ha! Just imagine 50 of them on your roof at 6 am ;)

Comment: A species-id question with [no research](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=blue+black+white+bird+canada) effort again. :)

Answer (score 17):

It's clearly a [magpie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magpie), a member of the crow family (*Corvidae*). There are many magpie species throughout the world, but since you say it's native to Canada, it must be the [black-billed magpie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-billed_magpie) (*Pica hudsonia*). There are only two magpie species native to Northern America, the other being the [yellow-billed magpie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow-billed_magpie) (*Pica nuttalli*), occuring in California.

[image]

**Image source:**

http://www.audubon.org/field-guide/bird/black-billed-magpie

Comment: Finally one of these silly questions I could answer and you beat me to it!